# Submenu is not working, angularjs html

Tags: angularjs, href, submenu

`

```js
app.controller('offerListCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 
function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get(baseURL + '/anager/getCoupon?token=' + token)
    .then(function(response) {


      $scope.artists = response.data.data;

    });
}]);
```

`I have this "openable" in my sidebar, it was working fine until I used NgRoute. This is in a view displayed by route and will generate more views as per clicks using function changeView(route).
Now When I click "Manage Retailer" to list its menu, it redirects to index page (which is login). I understand it is because that's how routing work, so I tried removing # in href and replace with href = "", that gives nothing nor the menu is opened. I tried removing href altogether, that doesn't work either. Please help me how can I make it work?

```html
<li class="xn-openable">
  <a href="#"><span class="fa fa-files-o"></span> <span class="xn-text">Manage Retailer</span></a>
  <ul>
    <li><a ng-click="changeView('addRetailer')" href=""><span class="fa fa-image"></span> Add Retailer</a></li>
    
    <li><a ng-click="changeView('retailerList')" href=""><span class="fa fa-user"></span> Retailer List</a></li>
    
    <li><a ng-click="changeView('addBranch')" href=""><span class="fa fa-users"></span> Add Branch</a></li>
    
    <li><a ng-click="changeView('branchList')" href=""><span class="fa fa-users"></span> Branch List</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

controller

Comment: Is the goal simply to have the anchor not redirect the page, and instead just open/close the menu?

Comment: Yes.. I am using a template for front-end, that is what it uses.

Comment: What happens if you make the `href` value `javascript:void(0)`?  Does that fix it?

Comment: It doesn't redirect to index but the sub-menu isn't opened still.

Comment: Hmmmm.... and if you omit the `href` completely?

Comment: Probably a scope issue. There is no easy answer because there can be different scopes (in an 'openable' directive, or the controller connected to your route). You should provide more code then just a html snippet.

Comment: I have added my controllers basic structure above too. Please take a look and let me know what could be causing this issue. Thanks